# I have a new notebook Le Novo ThinkPad E-14 which CtrlL key does not work when combined with other keys under Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, thinkpad

According to Ubuntu 20.04 help pressing Ctrl-Alt-T opens a terminal. However when I press the key combination CtrlL-Alt-T has no effect, where CtrlL means the left control key. On the other hand if I press the key combination CtrlR-Alt-T a terminal shell shows up clearly on the screen in agreement with Ubuntu 20.04 help statement. This experience was the same when I use my notebook for the first time and after I got a new keyboard through out claiming to Le Novo using the product waranty. The technical service advice me to report this results as a bug in Ubuntu 20.04.
I would be thankful in receiving an explanation to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference between using the left or right `[Ctrl]` keys on your notebook. That the key combination works when you use the right side but not the left does give a clue, though: your `[Fn]` and left `[Ctrl]` keys may be switched.

Perform this test. Try: `[Fn]`+`[Alt]`+`[T]`

If the terminal opens, then we know this is the case. You can swap the keys one of two ways:

1. via the BIOS at boot (pressing `[Fn]`+`[F2]`)
2. via the [BIOS Setup Utility in Windows](https://support.lenovo.com/in/en/solutions/HT074187)

Hope this helps

Comment: I appreciate your help, but pressing [Fn]+[Alt]+[T] fails to produce any effect, which means that there is no switching between the left [Ctrl] key with the [Alt] key.

Comment: Silly question, but have you confirmed that the left `[Ctrl]` key works? Are you able to `[Ctrl]`+`[C]` to copy text, for example? Alternatively, head to [KeyboardTester](https://www.keyboardtester.com/) to test that the key does in fact work.